# Why is my chess table not resetting before populating it?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm making a chess game and I start with an initial board. I have a position changing feature based on FEN. But when I want to update the board and reset before adding the new squares, it doesn't reset.

```
const board = () => {
    let squares = [];

    const setBoard = fen => {
        squares = [];
        //populating squares logic
    };

    return { squares, setBoard };
};
```

This is where I invoke this function:

```
const startingFEN = "r1b1kb1r/ppp1pp1p/2nq1np1/3p4/3P1Q2/1P2P1P1/P1P2P1P/RNB1KBNR w KQkq - 0 1";

const chessBoard = board();
chessBoard.setBoard(startingFEN);
drawBoard(chessBoard.squares);
```

And this is where I update the board (dom.js)

```
fenButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    chessBoard.setBoard(fenInput.textContent);
    drawBoard(chessBoard.squares);
});
```

the `squares = []` line in the `setBoard` function breaks the code, but without that line, it just adds an other board without resetting the previous one.

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more code context for us to be able to understand what is causing the issue here - the current snippet alone isn't enough to accurately diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns a reference to the array in the `squares` variable. By changing the value of a variable in a function, you do not change the passed value.

To clear an array in a variable, use `array.length = 0`.

Since the value of the variable should not change, use `const`.

```js
const board = () => {
    const squares = []; // use 'const'

    const setBoard = fen => {
        squares.length = 0; // clear squares
        //populating squares logic
    };

    return { squares, setBoard };
};
```